# Reset state before each Cypress test - TypeError: cy.resetDb is not a function

Tags: javascript, cypress

I use Cypress with my local web app. I followed install and run instructions:

https://github.com/gothinkster/react-mobx-realworld-example-app

Tests work fine until I wanted to reset database state according to the instructions:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#State-reset-should-go-before-each-test

I always get same error:

> TypeError: cy.resetDb is not a function

Any reccomendations how to fix that?

Comment: Do you actually *have* a resetDb command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `beforeEach` function to execute actions before every single test.

The Cypress documentation gives an example of how you can use `beforeEach`, but it expects you to implement the `resetDb` function. This is not a generic function supplied by Cypress.

Either remove the call to `resetDb` or implement it as a [Cypress Custom Command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, I assume there is no generic function to force use database in the same state at it used to be before star testing? Backend developer should prepare me one or there is any simpler solution for that?

Comment: @Piecho3a well how *would* Cypress know how to reset the database? It doesn't even know what DBMS you're using.